# Algorithm for smart cutting of text?

Tags: php

I am looking for an algorithm that when given a text will cut it to sentences smartly, anything could help. For now I have an algorithm that works with the number of words per sentence that I specify. I could change it to work till the first '.' and stuff like that but what I need is an algorithm that can do it somewhat logically (won't leave sentences that end on 'is' and 'and, and maybe look for other punctuation marks besides '.').

Any ideas?
I am using PHP5.

Comment: Could you be a little more precise about what you need. Maybe an example

Comment: nope, have to write something yourself maybe something like end after the first , OR . OR ! OR ? after the 300th char, if you dont find one till the 350th char end with the first whitespace after the 350th char?

Comment: I can write an algorithm myself, but it won't be as good as if I could find one that most people use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this code with [preg_split](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-split.php):

```
$sentences = preg_split("/[,.:;]+/", "Now you can split in sentences, try this. Isn't it good?");
```

It splits your sentence in an array of sentences, you have to choose which letter you want to use (in the example above I used ",.:;").
It uses regular expressions, it is very useful ;)

Comment: A problem is that it removes the ',' and '.' and I would later like to put those sentences back together to form the original text.

Comment: mmm it is more difficult... I try to search something